# In Doctrine 2, which locale setting exactly is relevant for the float mapping type?

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

The Doctrine documentation states [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html) that for the `float` mapping type the locale setting is relevant:

> -`float`: Type that maps a SQL Float (Double Precision) to a PHP double. **IMPORTANT**: Works only with locale settings that use decimal points as separator.

I am assuming that this refers to the locale setting of the SQL server, but there appears to be no more specific documentation, so it's read the source, run some tests, or ask here, in case someone has had to solve this already.

Answer (score 0):

From Doctrine 2.3, class `Doctrine\DBAL\Types\FloatType`:

```
public function convertToPHPValue($value, AbstractPlatform $platform)
{
    return (null === $value) ? null : (double) $value;
}
```

According to the PHP manual ([Converting to float](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php#language.types.float.casting), [Converting to integer](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting), [String conversion to numbers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion)), it seems that this will not support input values using comma as the decimal separator, hence the locale setting of the database server is likely being referred to in the Doctrine docs.

However, due to the peculiar ways PHP converts stuff into other stuff, if the database gives you `"10 Little Piggies"` in your supposed `float` column, the mapping above will "work", technically, although this is probably not what you want.

I am not sure if the Doctrine DBAL maybe performs other checks to make sure the input value has some meaning as a number. The input value arriving at this function is very likely dependent on the underlying database driver, as well.

Answer (score 0):

*"Works only with locale settings that use decimal points as separator."*
The locale settings refers here to the locale settings of your PHP code.
Doctrine would interpret it correctly ONLY if your PHP code would output the float value using . as a decimal separator.
There are locales where decimal separator is a comma (10,9 instead of 10.9).
The locale format using a comma as decimal separator would not work properly with Doctrine's float type.

If your float is locale formatted with decimal comma separator, you can re-format your number using the method parse in NumberFormatter class: http://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php

```
<?php
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'de_DE', NumberFormatter::DECIMAL );
echo $fmt->format(1234567.891234567890000)."\n";
$fmt = new NumberFormatter( 'it', NumberFormatter::SPELLOUT );
echo $fmt->format(1142)."\n";
?>
```